# How do the SetUp methods behave in an extended TestFixture class?

Tags: c#, nunit

I have two test classes, as in this example:

```
[TestFixture]
class BaseTest {

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupMethodA() {

    }

} 

[TestFixture]
class SomeTestFixture : BaseTest {

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupMethodB() {

    }

}
```

Is there a defined order for the two `SetUp` methods to be called in (`SetupMethodA` and `SetupMethodB`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [latest NUnit documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-Attribute#inheritance):

> if a base class has defined a SetUp method, that method will be called before each test method in the derived class.
>
> NUnit will call base class SetUp methods before those in the derived classes.

Comment: Right... one minor comment. The original code has TestFixture attribute on both classes. That's a bad habit because any Tests you put in the base will be executed twice. Best practice is to make the base abstract if you can.